# Invalid Parameter Number. Parameter not defined

Tags: php, yii

UPDATE2:

I've created a new WebUser.php component in /protected/components as follows:

```
<?php
class WebUser extends CWebUser{
private $_model;

function getId(){
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return $user->id;
}

protected function loadUser($id=null){
    if($this->_model===null)
    {
        if($id!==null)
        {
            $this->_model=Users::model()->findByPk($id);
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }       
}
}
```

I've registered the component in main.php as well.  After uploading changes, my app still states that WebUser.getId is not defined.

UPDATE:
After making changes and then rolling them back, I'm getting a new error:

```
Property "CWebUser.getId" is not defined.
```

The snippet of code in question is:

```
$user = Users::model()->find('username=?', array(
Yii::app()->user->getId));
```

How and where should getId be set to reference the $id field in the Users model?

My UserController is throwing the following SQL Error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:     
parameter was not defined. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `users` `t` WHERE 
username=? LIMIT 1
```

The error is being caused by this snippet of the controller:

```
public function actionProfile($id=''){        

        $user = Users::model()->find('username=?', array(Yii::app()->user->getId()));
        if(!$id){
            $id = $user->id;
            if(!$id)
            $this->redirect('login');
        }
        if( getUserSess('user_type') == 'Sitter') {
            $this->render('profile_detail', array('user_id' => $id ));
        } else {
            $this->render('petowner_profile_detail',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
        }
    }
```

The profile_detail view is as follows:

```
<?php
if(!$user_id){
    $user_id = getUserSess('id');
}
$this->widget('ext.UserProfile.BasicProfile',array('user_id'=>$user_id)); ?>
<?php //$this->widget('ext.UserProfile.UserServices',array('user_id'=>$user_id)); ?>
```

The petowner_profile_detail view is as follows:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'username',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'fname',
    'lname',
    'address1',
    'address2',
    'city',
    'state',
    'zip',
    'is_year_old',
    'user_type',
//      'register_date',
//      'varified_date',
//      'is_premium',
//      'last_login',
),
)); ?>
```

How do I rectify he SQL error?

Comment: In the line where you call `$user = Users::model()->find('username=?', array(Yii::app()->user->getId()));` what is the second parameter supposed to be? Maybe it's not supposed to be an `array`.

Comment: So, would I change this to $user = Users::model()->find('username=?', $id)); ?

Comment: if your intent is to search for `Yii::app()->user->getId()` just remove the `array()` part.

Comment: `$user = Users::model()->find('username=?', array(Yii::app()->user->getId()));` is absolutely fine, it'll work if you actually have a value in `Yii::app()->user->getId()`, so can you check that it is not null(within that action)?

Comment: @bool.dev Not sure that getID has a value.  Note that $id='' in the function statement.  How would I correct for this?

Comment: your latest error is because you are trying to access property `getId` instead of calling member function `getId()`. again can you check that getId() returns a value? i'm pretty sure that, that is the main issue here. you can do a simple var_dump or use CVarDumper and die(), although its not the best way to debug. before i can suggest something for the id, can you tell me if you are using any extension for this user functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

$user = Users::model()->find('username=:id', array(":id" => Yii::app()->user->id));

UPDATE2:

Yii::app()->user->getId() or Yii::app()->user->id not Yii::app()->user->getId